# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Tags: command-line, bash

i have this bash

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o nounset

if [ $# != 2 ]
then
    echo "Invalid arguments."
    echo "Try: $0 <Project Name> <Version>"
    exit
fi

if [ -d ./$1 ]; then
    echo "Error: Project $1 exists."
    exit
fi

vivado -mode batch -source create_vivado_proj.tcl -tclargs $1 $2

xsdk -batch -source create_sdk_proj.tcl $1 $2

curr_dir=`pwd`
project_dir="$curr_dir/$1"

# Create bootable files
mkdir "$project_dir/boot"
fsbl_path="$project_dir/$1.sdk/fsbl/Debug/fsbl.elf"
bit_path="$project_dir/$1.runs/impl_1/system_wrapper.bit"
config_path="$project_dir/$1.sdk/sysconfig/Debug/sysconfig.elf"
bif_path="$project_dir/boot/boot.bif"

echo "the_ROM_image:"               > $bif_path
echo "{"                            >> $bif_path
echo "     [bootloader]$fsbl_path"  >> $bif_path
echo "     $bit_path"               >> $bif_path
echo "     $config_path"            >> $bif_path
echo "}"                            >> $bif_path

# Create BOOT.bin
bootgen -image "$bif_path" -o i "$project_dir/boot/BOOT.bin"

echo "Generate BOOT.bin at"
echo "$project_dir/boot/BOOT.bin"
```

but when i run this code in terminal

```
./build.sh <Project ov7670_VDMA_VGA><v3>
```

i get this error

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
```

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Answer (score 1):

As two people commented, the syntax for calling the script uses characters that are not meant to be taken literally. The angle brackets in:

```
<Project Name> <Version>
```

imply that the Project Name and Version are required parameters. This is confirmed in the shell script code where it explicitly checks for two parameters:

```
if [ $# != 2 ]
then
    echo "Invalid arguments."
    ...
```

The correct way to call the script would be:

```
./build.sh "Project ov7670_VDMA_VGA" v3
```

... where I've quoted the first parameter so that the space between "Project" and "ov7670_VDMA_VGA" does not get *misinterpreted* as two separate arguments.